# python selenium selecting the correct input field

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, input-field

I am trying to select the correct input field to add a value to it. My current code partially works and it only selects to the first input field but I want to be able to manage which field I want to select and add
here is what the web structure looks like

```
<tr role="row" class="tester odd">
  <td class="hidden"></td>
  <td class="hidden">222</td>
  <td class="rester-table-cell">
    <input type="hidden" name="building[0].model" value="PeterAVE">
    <input type="text" name="building[0].size" class="control-input-num">
  </td>
  <td class="soreted_1" data-search="PeterAVE" data-order="PeterAVE">    
    <a href="/resilisting/p/PeterAVE">PeterAVE</a> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="tester even">
  <td class="hidden"></td>
  <td class="hidden">333</td>
  <td class="rester-table-cell">
    <input type="hidden" name="building[1].model" value="Sterling">
    <input type="text" name="building[1].size" class="control-input-num">
  </td>
  <td class="sorted_1" data-search="Sterling" data-order="Sterling">
    <a href="/resilisting/p/Sterling">Sterling</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am selecting my input field based on values [PeterAVE,Sterling, etc...] currently my code is only selecting and filling the input field for PeterAVE since it's the first one and there are hundreds that I want to be able to choose.

Here is the code I am using.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'control-input-num')] ").send_keys("1")
```

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the input fields with

```
input_fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('control-input-num')
```

and then select required by index

```
input_fields[10].send_keys('1')
```

You can also select input field by the value of preceding hidden input:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sterling']/following-sibling::input[@class='control-input-num']").send_keys("1")
```